# How to convert Windows GUID to boost::uuid?

Tags: c++, boost

I tried to get string for Windows GUID, but failed by using `boost::uuid`. The result is exact as this post [Boost uuid + boost endian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976983/boost-uuid-boost-endian) said, byte order wrong.

```
void foo(GUID& g)
{
  boost::uuids::uuid * u = reinterpret_cast<boost::uuids::uuid*>(&g);
  std::string ustr = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*u);
}
```

Finally, I used this post [Convert GUID structure to LPCSTR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555306/convert-guid-structure-to-lpcstr) to complete my convert.

But I am still curious,

1. Is there some elegant methods to convert any *types* to boost's ?
2. If there is, is there out-of-shelf libs for Windows' ?

Comment: code typo fixed according @jww

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> u = reinterpret_cast<boost::uuids::uuid*>(g);
> ```

I believe you should take the address of `g` in the `reinterpret_cast`:

```
u = reinterpret_cast<boost::uuids::uuid*>(&g);
```

Even if you do take the address, I think you have other troubles. Microsoft uses double words and words in their `GUID` structure, while Boost uses bytes.

***[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa373931(v=vs.80))***:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
    DWORD Data1;  WORD Data2;  WORD Data3;  BYTE Data4[8];
} GUID;
```

***[Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/uuid/uuid.hpp)***:

```
struct uuid
{
    ...
public:
    // or should it be array<uint8_t, 16>
    uint8_t data[16];
};
```

I believe you need to perform an explicit conversion with something like:

```
void MsToBoostUuid(const GUID& ms, boost::uuids::uuid& bst)
{
    bst.data[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data1 >> 24);
    bst.data[1] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data1 >> 16);
    bst.data[2] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data1 >>  8);
    bst.data[3] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data1 >>  0);

    bst.data[4] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data2 >> 8);
    bst.data[5] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data2 >> 0);

    bst.data[6] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data3 >> 8);
    bst.data[7] = static_cast<uint8_t>(ms.Data3 >> 0);

    bst.data[8] = ms.Data4[0];
    bst.data[9] = ms.Data4[1];
    ...
    bst.data[14] = ms.Data4[6];
    bst.data[15] = ms.Data4[7];
}

void foo(const GUID& g)
{
  boost::uuids::uuid u;
  MsToBoostUuid(g, u);

  std::string ustr = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(*u);
}
```

You can also add operators, like:

```
inline bool operator==(const& uuid lhs, const GUID& rhs)
{
    boost::uuids::uuid t;
    MsToBoostUuid(rhs, t);
    return std::equal(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), t.begin());
}

inline bool operator==(const GUID& lhs, const& uuid rhs)
{
    boost::uuids::uuid t;
    MsToBoostUuid(lhs, t);
    return std::equal(t.begin(), t.end(), rhs.begin());
}
```

---

> ... the result is exact as this post [Boost uuid + boost endian](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31976983/608639) said, byte order wrong.

I believe the currently accepted answer is incorrect. I believe Dutton's answer is correct, but it does not show you a typical conversion between UUID types.

Comment: Thanks @jww for this question. My curiosity is `MsToBoost` looks ugly. Is there some elegant methods to convert?   **AND** Is there an out-of-shelf libs for Windows-to-boost type covert?

Comment: @Raymond - None that I can find: [convert microsoft GUID to "boost::uuids::uuid" github](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+microsoft+GUID+to+"boost%3A%3Auuids%3A%3Auuid"+github). Any cross-platform conversion code you find is going to be similar to the code above. See, for example, Crypto++'s [`misc.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/misc.h) and Botan's [`loadstor.h`](https://github.com/randombit/botan/blob/master/src/lib/utils/loadstor.h). Everyone has to play the endian games.

Comment: Doesn't such a reinterpret_cast violate the current aliasing rules of the language?

Answer (score 1):

I've used this code with success:

```
boost::uuids::uuid MakeUUID(const GUID& guid)
{
    boost::uuids::uuid result;
    std::memcpy(&result, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(&guid), result.size());
    std::uint8_t* ch = reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(&result);
    std::swap(ch[0], ch[3]);
    std::swap(ch[1], ch[2]);
    std::swap(ch[4], ch[5]);
    std::swap(ch[6], ch[7]);
    return result;
}
```

It's the same thing as copying byte by byte, but using swap you get away with little less lines of code.